# Processing chunks of a dictionary with Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a very large dictionary that I have divided into several subdictionaries, the amount of subdictionaries is equal to the number of of multiprocessing.cpu_count().

I want to use a different process to run in parallel on each subdictionary so that I can save time. The goal of the script is to obtain triplets of data from the information in the dictionary, so I want to add the triplets found in every process to a different list (triplets_lists = [[triplets from process 1],[triplets from process 2],[triplets from process 3],[triplets from process 4]...]
Currently my code doesnt work, but it should be along the lines of this :

```
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        num_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        keys_list = list(largeDict.keys())
        random.shuffle(keys_list)
        subdict_size = len(keys_list) // num_cores
        subdicts = []   # list with the num_core amount of sub-dictionaries
        start_idx = 0
        triplets_lists = [[] for _ in range(num_cores)]   # a list containing all num_core amount of triplets lists
        processes = []
        for i in range(num_cores):
            end_idx = subdict_size * (i + 1)
            if i == (num_cores - 1):    # the last core gets all the remaning indexes in case it is not evenly divided by the num_cores variable
                end_idx = len(keys_list)
            subdicts.append({key: largeDict[key] for key in keys_list[start_idx:end_idx]})
            start_idx = end_idx
            process = multiprocessing.Process(target=processing_records, args=(subdicts[i], triplets_lists[i]))
            processes.append(process)
            process.start()
        for process in processes:
            process.join()
        print(triplets_lists)
```

The last print outputs an empty list, which i dont understand how.
The function processing_records() looks something like this:

```
def processing_records(smDict, triplets_list):
    for key, valuein smDict.items():
        for sentence in value:
            triplets = get_triplets(sentence)  # a function to obtain a list of all triplets in the sentence.
                for triplet in triplets:
                    triplets_list.append(t)
```

Comment: I have also used map() and apply_async() without much luck.

Comment: You canno't use the same namespaces between processes. Your list will be fill in a new list created in the process and then destoyed at the end without filling the one in your main process. You have to use a Queue (from multiprocessing library) or the Manager library to solve your problem. You should look some information about Pool to split your task in N processes.

Comment: Have you considered using imap() functionality with an explicit chunk size? Also, can you show what processing_records() does? It will help in finding a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in `triplets_lists` into your different processes it is not one single list that is shared between processes, it creates a copy that is modified by the process but the original `triplets_list` object in your main thread is never modified.

Try changing your `processing_records`  to something like this:

```py
def processing_records(smDict):
    triplets_list = []
    for key, valuein():
        for sentence in value:
            triplets = get_triplets(sentence)  # a function to obtain a list of all triplets in the sentence.
                for triplet in triplets:
                    triplets_list.append(t)
    return triplets_list
```

And then call it with:

```py
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=processing_records, args=subdicts[i])
```

This should give you what you want.

As a side note, you can also use a process pool to make the code a little more concise:

```py
# Create your subdicts object beforehand
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_cores)
triplets_list = pool.map(processing_records, subdicts)
```